# Understand the legs/parent/child of a Twilio call

Tags: twilio, twilio-php, twilio-api

How do I differentiate the caller and the callee on a Twilio call?

Is that why there's a parent call and a child call for each call that's made?

Also if I merge two persons into a conference room, how do I differentiate who is who?

I need this in order to build a hold feature, which will move each leg of the call to different conference rooms.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The caller and callee could be differentiated on the callback parameters as `$_REQUEST['CallFrom']` the caller and `$_REQUEST['CallTo']` the callee. Child calls will only happen if you use the `<Dial>` verb on an already started call; thus making the already started call the parent of the child call using `<Dial>`

You can identify each party in a conference by their **CallSid**
https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/conference

I would recommend you read some of the documentation on the above referenced link as most of the answers to your questions can be found there.

Comment: Ok that partially answers my question. But on a call that has no conference yet, let's say a <Dial> call. How do I identify each party of the call? Since on this case there will be only one CallSid ? Thanks!

Comment: When you have a <Dial> in an already existent call you can expect these two parameters  ParantCallSid, ChildCallSid. If you expand the call log in Twilio you should see these parameters being passed

Comment: So in this case the ParentCallSid means the first party (the caller), and ChildCallSid is for the callee?

Comment: Yes that is correct, as I said I would recommend you take a look at the logs on your twilio account and this will become very clear

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out. Btw, are you familiar with the PHP library? I'm trying to move both parties to a new URL, but I can't seem to find how to move them at the same time. If I move just one, the call hangs up the other party.